# Error in VSCode: 'Unable to find adb'. Adb is in the path of my Mac OS Catalina

Tags: macos, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, adb, macos-catalina

After upgrading to Mac Catalina I can't debug my ionic app anymore ...
When I try to debug on device or emulator it gives me this error.

> Attaching to android Unable to find adb. Please ensure it is in your
>   PATH and re-open Visual Studio Code

If I do on terminal inside or outside vscode

`$adb devices`

I get:

```
List of devices attached
42003f1d9610c50b    device
```

So **adb is in the path.**

I even tried to launch VSCode from terminal

```
code <myFolder>
```

after doing this:
[shell command install code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac)

But I still get the same error.

How can I tell VSCode the path to adb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set in .zshrc

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_HOME
PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"
```

And to see in VS Code The PATH environment variable process context.

open Help -> Toggle Developer Tools -> open Console ->

```
run console.log(process.env.PATH) command
```

And after updating Catalina is working !

Answer (score 0):

that is because in catalina the default shell changes and bash shell's saved paths no longer work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Vasu Chawla. Do you have a suggestion how I can tell Visual Studio Code the path to adb ?

Comment: copy the contents of ~/.bash_profile to ~/.zshrc and restart VS Code